# How to display Array value using timeout function?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

i have a array of values given below

```
var itelmlist=[{“page”:”url1”,”time”:”20”},     {"page":"url2”,”time”:”25”},     {"page":"url3”,”time”:”10”},     {"page":"url4”,,”time”:”12”},     {"page":"url5”,”time”:”5”},     {"page":"url6”,”time”:”9”},     {"page":"url7”,”time”:”5”},     {"page":"url8”,”time”:”10”},     {"page":"url9”,”time”:”10”} ];
```

above array is a json array in that two key values "page" and "time",page is an external url and time is the time i need to display that page. i need to display each page for that particular time duration. i tried in angular for each but not working.

How can i do that ?Thanks in advance

Comment: I can't understand the question. Elaborate. Show what you have tried.

Comment: What do you mean by "display a page"? Where should the page be displayed? What is the time? What's the unit? Is it a relative time? Relative to what? Why do I have to harass you with questions to get these informations. If you want help, ask a clear question. And show what you have tried.

Comment: there is a time field in your object. Do you intend to use them?

Comment: i am creating an app so i need to display the external page in the app,time is the field present in that object the time is in second @JB Nizet

Comment: You can create a custom directive with initialising iframe inside it maybe and upon $interval timeout as mentioned in answer below you can switch sources of URL. You might want to identify if the page is loaded and then initialise a timer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your time measures but you can use interval function:

```
$interval(function() {
            //your function.. check if the time is correct
          }, 100);
```

Every 100 miliseconds this function will be invoked.